# Logarithmic Regression by hand

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

I'm trying to write some code to do a regression on data weight (x) and time (y). As best as I can tell, the model should be y = b1 + b2ln(x), but I don't know how you can do this by hand (I know how to in R...). I know how to do a simple linear regression by hand. Appreciate it.

Comment: calculate logs: x1 = ln(x). Regress y on x1. Done. BTW your model is wrong unless your errors are all 0 (in which case you can just compute it from any two distinct points). That is, you either need to write $E(y)=$ or you need to add $+e$ on the end

Comment: can it be done using the least squares approach?

Comment: That's what I'm saying up there, yes. How are you doing it in R if not by least squares?

Comment: I guess I'm not exactly sure lol. So normally you would calculate SXX = sum(x-xbar)^2; SXY = sum((x-xbar)(y-ybar)); SYY = sum(y-ybar)^2. Then B1 = SXY/SXX. How would this differ given the log term?

Comment: The *entire* thing is in my first comment. Try reading it again, please. It has two steps. Tell me what you don't understand about step 1 (Calculate the logs, calling the result $x_1$). If you understand what that means, we can move to step 2.

Comment: Am I just taking all of my x data points and applying ln to them? Giving me a new set of data points?

Comment: Yes. That's it exactly.

Comment: Ok, then from there I just proceed like normal?

Comment: Yes, treating the new variable as if it were $x$. I'll post an example for you to follow.

Comment: Example posted (I round off the numbers a bit when I take logs to save you some calculation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that you'd calculate the slope as follows:

> So normally you would calculate
>
> $$S_{XX} = \sum_i (x_i-\bar x)^2\\ 
> S_{XY} = \sum_i ((x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y))\\ 
> S_{YY} = \sum(y_i-\bar y)^2$$
>
> Then $b_2 = S_{XY}/S_{XX}$.

So imagine you have a set of x-values and y-values:

```
    y       x
1 2.3 0.36772
2 5.3 1.64873
3 6.5 7.38910
```

Step 1:

calculate a new $x$, $x_1 = \ln(x)$

```
    y   x1
1 2.3 -1.0
2 5.3  0.5
3 6.5  2.0
```

Now regress $y$ on this new $x_1$ as usual

```
 SXX = 4.50; SXY= 6.30; SYY = 9.36

 b2 = SXY/SXX = 1.4

 b1 = mean(y) - b2 . mean(x) = 4.7 - 1.4 . 0.5 = 4
```

[image]